# How to add Mobile field in Registration form using Theme my login Plugin

Tags: plugins, user-registration

I have created a new PHP file in the plugins folder and added the code:

```php
function add_tml_registration_form_fields() {
    tml_add_form_field( 'register', 'phone', array(
        'type'     => 'tel',
        'label'    => 'Mobile Number',
        'value'    => tml_get_request_value( 'phone', 'post' ),
        'id'       => 'phone',
        'priority' => 15,) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_tml_registration_form_fields' );

function validate_tml_registration_form_fields( $errors ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'empty_phone', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter your mobile number.' );
    }
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'validate_tml_registration_form_fields' );

function save_tml_registration_form_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['phone'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'save_tml_registration_form_fields' );
```

But I am getting error. please refer to this image: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/5706632/f5c513616090709c1ee6faa42bc6afeb

Please suggest some help.

Comment: That looks like it's just printing out your PHP, not an error. Is this code in a PHP block, i.e. do you have `<?php` before these lines or at the start of the file?

Comment: (Note there's a missing } at the end of validate_tml_registration_form_fields. That was missing in the original - I didn't remove it when I reformatted the code block.)